# How to display Parent Page Title in AEM Sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

I want to display parent page title of the page just above my current page.How do i do that in sighlty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of [global objects](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/global-objects.html) available to Sightly in an AEM Application.

As mentioned by rakhi4110, one of the objects is `currentPage`, which is an instance of the [Page class](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html). `Page` has the `getParent()` method available. However since this might return null you should probably wrap your usage in a test:

```
<h1 data-sly-test="${currentPage.parent}">
    ${currentPage.parent.title}
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${currentPage.parent.title}` or `${currentPage.getParent.getTitle}` to get the title of the parent page.